# Overwritten session variable

Tags: session, iis, coldfusion, proxy

I've a problem with session variable in a Coldfusion project running on IIS 6.
If I access the site not behind a proxy everything works fine, but if I login behind a proxy (from client side obviously) it works normally at first, but when a second user login, the first one assumes the second one's identity on page refresh.
It's like the session variable on server is being overwritten on each login.

Could you help me?

This is my code for setting session

```
<cfquery name="qCheckUser" datasource="#myDataSource#">
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '#username#' and pwd = '#pwd#'
</cfquery>

<cflock scope="session" type="exclusive" timeout="10">
    <cfset session.userID = qCheckUser.userID>
</cflock>
```

Username and pwd come from a classic login form.
Then I use session.userID to retrieve the userId after the login.

Comment: _"Could you help me?"_  - not without seeing your session/login code.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647604/coldfusion-session-issue-multiple-users-behind-one-proxy-ip-cftoken-and-cfi

Comment: How are you learning about this?  Are you running the page yourself with different logins?

Comment: I've people doing test behind the firewall. They reported this test to  me on the phone.

Comment: Do you have setClientCookies = 'no' anywhere in your CFAPPLICATION tag or application.cfc/cfm?

Comment: @Mino, are these people using the same computer at the same time?

Comment: You might want to look at how things are being cached on your proxy and at the HTTP headers flowing between the client and the server.  Where I work, we've had problems in the past where the proxy server was caching responses and then serving up those responses when it shouldn't have.

Comment: do you have `Use J2EE session variables` checked?