# cflocation and session variables

Tags: coldfusion

My user comes from a 3rd party site via http post with login credentials encrypted in the URL.

Once the index.cfm recognizes these variables, it sends the  request to:

```
 <cflocation url="login.cfm?vals=#URLEncodedFormat(url.vals)#" addtoken="yes">
```

The login.cfm builds a session struct if the login credentials are valid.

```
   Session.user.userID = 1;
   Session.user.firstName = "jo";
   Session.user.lastName = "boo";
```

Then, it does:

```
 <cflocation url="somepage.cfm" addtoken="yes">
```

When I dump the session variable in somepage.cfm, I do not see the session.user struct. Also, I keep seeing different cfid, cftoken on somepage.cfm every single I refresh. I am on ColdFusion 10.

Any ideas? How can I keep the session.user?

Edit: application.cfc has

```
   this.name            = "My Application";
   this.applicationTimeout  = createTimeSpan(0,2,0,0);  
   this.clientManagement    = true;
   this.loginStorage    = "session";
   this.sessionManagement   = true;
   this.sessionTimeout      = createTimeSpan(0,0,30,0); 
   this.setClientCookies    = true;
   this.setDomainCookies    = false;
   this.scriptProtect   = "all";
   this.javaSettings    = {LoadPaths = ["#GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath())#java/"], reloadOnChange=true, watchInterval=180};
```

EDIT: here are the files
     http://1drv.ms/1kjnQO2

Unzip them to your C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\

then go to :

```
http://localhost:8500/test/call.cfm
```

---

EDIT: 19:00 - 10Jun:

Wow, this really sucked! Came home, downloaded the zip, opened it up to localhost. When I run, I can see the session.user variables from call.cfm.

```
  <cfdump var="#server#">
```

gives me:

```
 coldfusion 
 struct
 InstallKit  Native Windows
 appserver   J2EE
 expiration  {ts '2012-10-30 10:35:35'}
 productlevel    Developer
 productname     ColdFusion Server
 productversion  10,0,0,283111
 rootdir     C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion
```

I am not sure if this has something to do with the CF server version.

UPDATE: 09:00 11-Jun. 
Once I disable "Use J2EE session variables " in CFAdmin, the session variables are visible to call.cfm. Now, I have to make it work with J2EE session variables when they are enabled.

Comment: is your login crossing the user from HTTP to HTTPS?

Comment: Sounds like the browser isn't retaining CFID and CFTOKEN cookies. What are your settings for session handling in Application.cfc?

Comment: How do you pass the login credentials from index.cfm to login.cfm?

Comment: Are you doing anything else with the encrypted URL variables in index.cfm? If not, those values will never get to login.cfm. `cflocation` will not automatically add URL (or any other scoped variables) to the request.

Comment: @DanBracuk index.cfm passes the encrypted url parameter to login.cfm. Then, login.cfm has some logic to decrypt this parameter, query the DB to see if it is a valid user.

Comment: @ScottStroz, the cflocation tag actually has a url parameter attached to it. Please see the original post.

Comment: @FALCONSEYE ...ok good deadl. Two other questions are you hopping subdomains like goingFromHere.myDomain.com to landingHere.myDomain.com?  Second question what version of Coldfusion are you using?

Comment: @FrankTudor 1.No, 2.CF10. thanks

Comment: Well...that wasn't there when I asked the question.

Comment: Try dumping session scope (and aborting) before the `cflocation` to somepage.cfm.

Comment: @FALCONSEYE You have two redirects, right?  Break your second cflocation to see what might be happening there.  Do you have conditional logic in that page you are calling somepage.cfm?  Do you have cflocation redirectors in your conditional logic that checks for not right/don't match/or whatever...What do you do then? I have a feeling you actually have 4 redirects.  You redirect failures, yes? You should give us page one and page two code so we can explore the conditional logic.

Comment: @ScottStroz. the session variables i set before the cflocation to somepage.cfm page is there. I see them with cfdump. I will try to put some sample code together. thanks

Comment: What browser are you using? Does it happen in IE, Chrome and FF or just one or more, but not all, browsers?

Comment: @ScottStroz, i tested with chrome and ff. it happens on both.

Comment: Have you read this article from Adobe? [Missing session variables when using the cflocation tag](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/missing-session-variables-using-cflocation.html)  It may be old but still relevant.

Comment: I also found this bug - [ColdFusion 10.0 - Bug 3430245 Session gets lost on cflocation width J2EE Sessions and Cookies disabled](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3430245)

Comment: @Miguel-F I am not using any locks. Therefore, I do not think that this is applicable in here. Feel free to download the code, play with J2EE session via admin and go nuts! :(  The bug (Bug 3430245) sounds like my issue. Grrr.